# VS Code: "go to definition" not working on exported class

Tags: javascript, annotations, visual-studio-code, definition

I can't use "go to definition" feature in VS Code on `exported` class clicking on property type annotation. Here is example:

```
//Core.js
export default class Core { constructor() {} }

//Engine.js
export default class Engine{
    /** @type {Core} core */
    constructor(core) {
        /** @type {Core} */            
        this.core = core;
    }
} 

//index.js
import Core from './Core';
import Engine from './Engine';

const core = new Core();
const engine = new Engine(core);
```

When I am in Engine.js and want to go to class Core.js by clicking on annotation {Core} it doesn't work. If I use "go to definition", VS code says: No definition found for 'Core'.

What I am doing wrong?
Is it even possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@typedef` annotation to "import" the type into the file, like so:

```
/** @typedef {import('./Core').default} Core */

export default class Engine{
    /** @type {Core} core */
    constructor(core) {
        /** @type {Core} */            
        this.core = core;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your file hierarchy of the project.  Most probably you are not defining your import starting from the root directory of the project.

```
import Page from 'components/Page'; //1


import Page from './../components/Page'; //2
```

1 does not work for me, but 2 does.